# OpenCV - How to split a image to two regions by a oblique line?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I'm using `HoughLinesP` to detect lines in a image. The result is a oblique line. I want to do some operations(erode and dilate) on the region under the line.

So I want ask how to split the image by this line into two regions(region0 and region1) or deal the region1 without split image.

For example, the image size is `200*100`, and line is `(0, 50, 200, 75)`.

If the line is horizontal or vertical, I can use `image[y:y+h, x:x+w]` to crop the image when I get the rect(x, y, w, h) of crop area. But I have no idea for oblique line.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: What is the expected output?  Images by definition have to be rectangular.

Comment: In fact, I just do some operations in region1 not in region0. So I want to split image. If there is some ways to deal only region1 without split image, thats OK.

Comment: We can define two masks that define the two regions. That way, whatever operations you do on each region, the zeroed out areas would not be processed. However, I have a feeling this is a XY problem. Can you describe what operations you're intending to do in these regions?

Comment: Erode and dilate.

Comment: Ok then would it be acceptable to define two masks?

Comment: Yes, seems get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice-op` to get an `rectangle`, and `mask-op` to get `non-rectangle` like this.

[image]

Basic steps are:

1. define an empty image.
2. define the corner points.
3. drawContours in the empty image (with filled)
4. do mask-op

My Python3-OpenCV3.3 Code:

```
## Step 1-3: drawContours in empty image
mask = np.zeros((100,200), np.uint8)
pts = np.array([[0,0],[0,50],[199,75],[199,0]])
_=cv2.drawContours(mask, np.int32([pts]),0, 255, -1)

## Step 4: do mask-op
img1 = img.copy()
img2 = img.copy()
img1[mask==0] = 0
img2[mask>0] = 0

## Write
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("img1.png", img1)
cv2.imwrite("img2.png", img2)
```

Here are images and the result：

src and mask:

[image: src] [image: mask]

results:

[image: res1] [image: res2]

Comment: Use `result[mask==0] = img2[mask==0]` and `result[mask>0] = img1[mask>0]` to merge, right?

Comment: yeah, you can try it

Comment: I wonder if we only have two points, and we don't know which two corner points to include when drawing contours, then how to obtain the mask in this case? Thank you